# Equivalence relation/classes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Define a relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{N}$ as follows. For any $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$, $m \sim n$ if and only if $mn$ is a perfect square. Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. What are the equivalence classes?
I have proven equivalence relation but not any sure about what the equivalence classes are.

Answer (score 1):

It is reasonably straightforward to show that each $\sim$-equivalence class has a unique squarefree representative, that is, a unique element $n$ such that every prime the prime factorisation of $n$ appears with multiplicity $1$. Moreover, distinct squarefree natural numbers are in distinct $\sim$-equivalence classes.

Thus the $\sim$-equivalence classes are in bijection with the squarefree natural numbers.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the equivalence class of an element $a \in \mathbb{N} = [a] = \{n \in \mathbb{N} | a \sim n\} = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} | \ a n$ is a perfect square $\}$.

Comment: True, but not very helpful.